# Structural typing and user-defined type guards

Tags: typescript, structural-typing

```
type GraphQLType =
    | GraphQLInt
    | GraphQLList<any>
    | GraphQLNonNull<any>;

interface GraphQLInt {
  int: number
}

interface GraphQLList<T> {
  x: string
}

interface GraphQLNonNull<T> {
  x: string
}

declare function isInt(type: GraphQLType): type is GraphQLInt;
declare function isList(type: GraphQLType): type is GraphQLList<any>;
declare function isNonNull(type: GraphQLType): type is GraphQLNonNull<any>;

function doIt(t: GraphQLType) {
  if (isInt(t)) {
    return t.int
  }

  if (isList(t)) {
    // t: GraphQLList<any> | GraphQLNonNull<any>
    return t.x
  }

  // t: never

  if (isNonNull(t)) {
    return t.x
  }
}
```

The example above causes an error in the isNonNull() block because it determines t to be of type never. In the isList() block t has both types GraphQLList and GraphQLNonNull. Both types are structurally the same. Is this the same problem described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5518) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7271) or is it actually a bug?

The reason it should work is because isList() is a type guard for GraphQLList and not GraphQLNonNull, and at runtime it will return true for a List and false for a NonNull, but typescript doesn't seem to be representing the same idea.

Comment: TypeScript's support for nominal typing (types with different names are different types) is minimal or nonexistent.  If you want TypeScript to know that two types are different, it's best for them to differ *structurally*.  There is no structural difference between `GraphQLList` and `GraphQLNonNull` (and neither of them use their type parameter `T`).  If you want this to work, give them some different properties.

Comment: Relevant [FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-prevent-two-types-from-being-structurally-compatible)

Comment: neither of them use their type parameter T: 
that's just for this example.
I can't change the types, they come from GraphQL.js

Answer (score 1):

Type guards will work by narrowing the type of the varible to anything that is assigable to the guarded type

Ex:

```
function isString(s: any) : s is { o: string } {
    return typeof s.o === 'string'; 
}

let s!: number | { o: 'a', n: number } | { o : 'b', b: boolean};
if(isString(s)) {
    s // { o: 'a', n: number } | { o : 'b', b: boolean}
}
```

The two types in the union that are narrowed to in the `if` are not exactly of the guarded type but are assignable to it, so both types end up in the narrowed type, while `number` does not since it is not assignable to `{ o : string }`.

Applying the same logic to your example, it does not much matter to typescript that the types are nominally different, since both `GraphQLList` and `GraphQLNonNull` are assignable to each other any guard for one will select both types.

As @jcalz points out in the comments, the best you can do is make the types structurally incompatible in some way that does not have much of an impact. The simplest way to do this is to add an optional unique symbol to each interface:

```
type GraphQLType =
    | GraphQLInt
    | GraphQLList<any>
    | GraphQLNonNull<any>;

interface GraphQLInt {
    int: number
}

interface GraphQLList<T> {
    x: string
    readonly __u?: unique symbol;
}

interface GraphQLNonNull<T> {
    x: string
    readonly __u?: unique symbol;
}

declare function isInt(type: GraphQLType): type is GraphQLInt;
declare function isList(type: GraphQLType): type is GraphQLList<any>;
declare function isNonNull(type: GraphQLType): type is GraphQLNonNull<any>;

function doIt(t: GraphQLType) {
    if (isInt(t)) {
        return t.int
    }

    if (isList(t)) {
        // t: GraphQLList<any>
        return t.x
    }

    // t: GraphQLNonNull<any>

    if (isNonNull(t)) {
        return t.x
    }
}
```

**Edit**

You note that the types come from `GraphQL` you can use module augmentation and interface merging to extends the interfaces.